# Theme not applied using appcompat library on some Android 4.X devices

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat, android-theme

After updating the appcompat library to the latest version (v21) to apply the material design, my custom theme isn't used anymore on Android 4.0.X devices unless I explicitly declare it in the XML.

I have tested the theme on Android 2.3.X and 5.0.0 devices and it works on those devices. But it's not working on my HTC One S with Android 4.0.3. What do I need to do to fix this?

My themes.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Custom" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/Custom.Widget.EditText</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Custom.Widget.Button</item>
</style>
```

My styles.xml

```
<style name="Custom.Widget.EditText" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/text_hint_color</item>
</style>

<style name="Custom.Widget.Button" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_default_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">64dip</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_text_primary</item>
</style>
```

My layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <!-- other elements -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/view_username_edit_username_editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textCapSentences"
            android:hint="@string/UsernameScreen_usernameHint"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLength="@integer/username_max_length"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/view_username_save_Button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view_username_edit_username_editText"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:text="@string/common_save" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If I add the following to lines in the layout files it works. So there seems to be going something wrong with the themes.xml.

```
style="@style/Custom.Widget.EditText"
style="@style/Custom.Widget.Button"
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Expected:

[image: Expected]

**Edit**

I tested the same code on some other devices.

- Samsung S2 (4.0.4): OK
- HTC One (4.4.3): OK
- HTC One X (4.0.3): NOK
- HTC One S (4.1.1): NOK
- HTC Desire C (4.0.3): NOK

I don't see why it wouldn't work on some of these devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to my problem. I was using `@style/Theme.AppCompat` as a parent to one of my styles. After changing it to `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` it works on all devices. I still find it very strange why this would screw up my styling.

Answer (score 6):

I after add buttonStyle without the "android:" prefix and it solved the problem. 
(name="android:buttonStyle" -> name="buttonStyle")

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/SkinedButton</item>
</style>
```