# AppCompat Custom theme not applying

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I generated a custom theme using the Android Asset Studio Actionbar styling tool.  I am not able to view the theme.  I only get the AppCompat.Light or AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar base theme in my app.  (I also referred to this article [Theme not applied using appcompat library on some Android 4.X devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603189/theme-not-applied-using-appcompat-library-on-some-android-4-x-devices))

My values/styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Betbuds" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_betbuds</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Betbuds</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Betbuds</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Betbuds</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Betbuds</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Betbuds</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_betbuds</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_betbuds</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Betbuds</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Betbuds" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_betbuds</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_betbuds</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_betbuds</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Betbuds</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Betbuds" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_betbuds</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Betbuds</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.Betbuds" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_betbuds</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.Betbuds" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_betbuds</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Betbuds" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_betbuds</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.Betbuds" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_betbuds</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_betbuds</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_betbuds</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Betbuds" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_betbuds</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Betbuds" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_betbuds</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Betbuds.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Betbuds</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Betbuds</item>
</style>
```

My values-v14/styles.xml

```
    <style name="Theme.Betbuds" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_betbuds</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Betbuds</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Betbuds</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Betbuds</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Betbuds</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Betbuds</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_betbuds</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_betbuds</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Betbuds</item>


    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Betbuds" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_betbuds</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_betbuds</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_solid_betbuds</item>
        <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Betbuds</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Betbuds" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_betbuds</item>
        <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Betbuds</item>
    </style>

    <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Betbuds.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Betbuds</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Betbuds</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

The Android Studio preview also shows only the Base themes.  I have the following in my Manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Betbuds" >
```

I realise that there are a lot of questions similar to this.  I am not able to figure out an answer.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Probably because the tool is deprecated with the introduction of `Toolbar`.

Comment: I merged the two XMLs into the single styles.xml.  I verified the styles and they are not deprecated.  Now I get the background color in the ActionBar. But the PagerTabStrip is not getting the styles.